# AngularJS automatic log out when closing browser window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, window, passport.js

I am writing an app using AngularJS and PASSPORT to authenticate. I want to have the functionality where when logged in, a user automatically gets logged out when the browser window closes.

This is my log out function in my factory:

```
app.factory('authenticate', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window){
   authenticate.logOut = function(){
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
   };
```

and I tried to add this to a script at the bottom of the html:

```
window.onbeforeunload = logOut();
```

But this does not work. What should I do differently?

Comment: remove the parens when making the assignment

Comment: Why don't you use sessionStorage instead of localStorage? "sessionStorage" has exactly the behaviour you need - everything is removed from it when the browser is closed.

Comment: removing the parens didn't work @dandavis

Comment: alos, use `onunload` instead of `onbeforeunload`

Comment: window.onunload = logOut; still not working @dandavis

Comment: `window.onunload=function(){localStorage.token="";};`

Comment: Thank you but this does not work as well @dandavis and neither does           window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  localStorage.removeItem(token);
  return '';
};

Comment: Nvm I came up with a working solution!!   localStorage.clear(); @dandavis thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: Re: sessionStorage, only works for the one tab. Not multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(authenticate)
{
    authenticate.logOut();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: And neither does window.onbeforeunload = authenticate.logOut();

Comment: What if you're just doing a browser refresh?

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is when using localStorage is localStorage.clear();

Comment: I think is not the best way, in fact I think is easy but really bad way. Because you will destroy all the information from others scripts in the localStorage as well.